# Как преобразовать дату в юлианском представлении в DATE со временем?

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно преобразовать значение даты в юлианском представлении в обычную дату со временем.

```
Select to_char(to_date(2455198, 'J'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Этот запрос работает и его результат: `01-01-2010 12:00:00`

```
Select to_char(to_date(2455197.75001, 'J'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') from dual;
```

А запрос выше не работает и выдает ошибку:

> ORA-01830: шаблон формата даты завершается перед преобразованием всей строки ввода
> 01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Для значения юлианской даты: `2455197.75001` ожидаю: `1-January-2010 06:00:01`.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle query for Convert from Julian value to Date with Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64769927) от участника [@Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6290176/jack)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64769927

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя использовать дробные числа со значением юлианской даты. Как [говорится в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A):

> **J**  - Julian day; the number of days since January 1, 4712 BC.
> Number specified with J **must be integers.**

Поэтому, для получения значения даты с маской `J` можно использовать ф-ии `floor` или `trunc`, а дробную часть использовать как количество неполных дней. Так как [юлианский день](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) начинается в полдень, а не в полночь, то следует добавить еще полдня:

```
select to_char(
    to_date(floor(julanday), 'J') + mod(julanday, 1) + 0.5, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
from (select 2455197.75001 julanday from dual);
```

Что даст результат (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2db0e57d4f8cf920266f3f4dc8905cc)):

> 01-01-2010 06:00:01

---

<sub>Свободныe переводы ответов [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770199) и [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770440) от участников [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon) и [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)</sub>